# Use my method after moving it to another class

Tags: android

I wrote a code that uses `OnTouchListener` like this: when I click on the Imageview that I set on my layer, I Can move it around the screen (using the event: DOWN, MOVE and Up.

Now I wanted to move the lines of code I wrote inside the OnTouchListener to another Class which I named: **"DragAndDrop"** and inside of it to a method which I named **"action"**. The code worked perfectly fine until I moved it to another class, after I moved it I could not move the Imageview on the screen. Also I tried to put the code inside a method inside the MainActivity Class and it worked perfectly fine. only when I moved it to anouther class it stopped working.
this is what I wrote:

**On the Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public DragAndDrop dragAndDrop;

   public ImageView face_no_face;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        face_no_face = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.face_no_face);
        face_no_face.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                dragAndDrop =   new DragAndDrop();
                dragAndDrop.action(v,   event,  face_no_face);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**On the DragAndDrop class:**

```
public class DragAndDrop {

    private float   x,y=0.0f;
    private boolean moving;

   public void action(View v, MotionEvent event,    ImageView   face_no_face) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                moving = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (moving) {
                    x = event.getRawX() - face_no_face.getWidth()   /2;
                    y = event.getRawY() - face_no_face.getHeight()  *3    /2;
                    face_no_face.setX(x);
                    face_no_face.setY(y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                moving = false;
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should initialize `DragAndDrop ` class outside of the `onTouch` function. Only call it's `action` function inside the `onTouch` event.

Comment: @aborocz Thank you very much brother it worked! I'm new in Android Studio so I guess I messed up a preety Obvious thing right? If so can you please tell me why now it is working and before it did not? Does it has to do something with that the initialization of the subclasses have to be on the constructor of the parent class?

Comment: Or is it because I should'nt initialize a Class instance inside of an @Overrid method? And if so then why?